# Why query takes ages when I filter by an indexed boolean column?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a query that filters on a `boolean` column that has index. But, the query takes ages to finish. When I don't use this filter, the query returns very quickly.

Here are the explain plans. The first one has the `processed is true` and takes ages to finish. The second one does not have it and returns immediately.

```
explain select count(*) from listen_events where (started_at >='2021-12-26' and started_at <'2021-12-27') and processed is true;
                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=212405.62..212405.63 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on listen_events  (cost=187657.78..212390.09 rows=6213 width=0)
         Recheck Cond: ((started_at >= '2021-12-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (started_at < '2021-12-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Filter: (processed IS TRUE)
         ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=187657.78..187657.78 rows=6213 width=0)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_listen_events_on_started_at  (cost=0.00..17323.56 rows=813898 width=0)
                     Index Cond: ((started_at >= '2021-12-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (started_at < '2021-12-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on listen_events_processed_idx  (cost=0.00..170330.87 rows=9125639 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (processed = true)
(9 rows)

=> explain select count(*) from listen_events where (started_at >='2021-12-26' and started_at <'2021-12-27');
                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=24549.13..24549.14 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=24548.92..24549.13 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=23548.92..23548.93 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using index_listen_events_on_started_at on listen_events  (cost=0.58..22701.11 rows=339124 width=0)
                     Index Cond: ((started_at >= '2021-12-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (started_at < '2021-12-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
(6 rows)
```

Here is the table configuration:

```
Table "public.listen_events"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('listen_events_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 event_type     | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 stream_type    | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 event_id       | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 broadcast_uid  | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 user_agent     | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 city           | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 country        | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 referrer       | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 country_code   | character varying(2)        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 continent_code | character varying(2)        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 user_id        | integer                     |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 started_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 ip_address     | cidr                        |           |          |                                           | main     |              | 
 location       | point                       |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 ended_at       | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 server_id      | text                        |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 channel_id     | integer                     |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 id_bigint      | bigint                      |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 processed      | boolean                     |           | not null | false                                     | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "listen_events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_listen_events_event_id" btree (event_id)
    "index_listen_events_on_broadcast_uid" btree (broadcast_uid)
    "index_listen_events_on_started_at" btree (started_at)
    "index_listen_events_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
    "listen_events_processed_idx" btree (processed)
Options: autovacuum_enabled=true, autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0, autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=30000, autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=0, autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0, autovacuum_analyze_threshold=30000, toast.autovacuum_enabled=true
```

Currently, the table has 1.9 billion rows and the majority has `processed = false`.

Any clue why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, so I am reduced to guessing. Anyway there are two main differences:

1. Since there is no single index for the query, PostgreSQL combines two indexes. That is some more work than scanning a single index.
2. The main difference is that the fast query can use an index-only scan, while the slow query cannot.

I'd create a two-column index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON listen_events (processed, started_at);
```

If you only ever query for rows with `processed IS TRUE`, you could also create a smaller and faster index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON listen_events (started_at) WHERE processed IS TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I create the index on two columns, `processed, started_at`, do I still need the separate index on the `processed` column only?

Comment: No, that should be unnecessary.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos: if you create the index to only support the query in your question, I would go for the filtered index.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos: With your given cardinalities I would certainly aim for the much smaller partial index. Since only `true` qualifies in a `WHERE`clause, you can generally simplify `WHERE processed IS TRUE` to just `WHERE processed`.